# Magic: the Gathering - Modern Engineering

Tags: calculation-puzzle, magic-the-gathering

**The Challenge**
Using only lands and artifacts, your goal is to build a Modern-legal Magic: the Gathering deck that is capable of winning the game as quickly as possible, against an opponent who does nothing. You may assume that your deck is stacked, so that you will always draw exactly the cards you want.

Your opponent's deck consists of sixty islands, they begin the game by mulliganing to zero, and will take no actions unless required to. Your solution may not involve random chance, or the opponent choosing to do something suicidal.

**Scoring**
The best solution is the one which can defeat the opponent in as few turns as possible. You may choose to play or draw, but winning on the play is faster than winning on the draw.
If two solutions are equally fast, the better solution is the one that deals more damage (or life-loss).
If two solutions are equally fast and equally damaging, the better solution is the one that uses less cards.
If your solution involves taking extra turns, it will be scored based on how many turns your opponent got. If the opponent never gets a turn, that's a turn 1 win. If the opponent takes one turn before you win, that's turn 2, and so on.

**Why Modern-legal artifacts?**
I've tested it, and I believe the restriction achieves an interesting level of complexity, with neither a dead simple four card solution, nor an optimal fifty-card monster solution.

Plus, it lends itself to a great puzzle title.

Comment: Are we allowed to use Artifact Creatures?

Comment: Yes, anything with the Artifact type.

Comment: @Ninety-Three Just an fyi, in the future, I would recommend measuring the winner by number of phases passed through, instead of saying that T1 on the draw is automatically slower than T1 on the play. While not normally relevant, and I don't think it is for this question, "Gemstone Caverns" is a card that may make it possible to win on your opponent's upkeep while being T1 on the draw, which would be faster than T1 on the play main phase.

Comment: "or the opponent choosing to do something suicidal." aside from playing with a deck of nothing but lands ??  O.o  lol

Comment: @Ditto I don't know what you're talking about, the opponent is playing a deck of nothing but the best card in Magic. They are obviously a wise and powerful wizard, who would never pick 20 on Choice of Damnations.

Comment: @Waterseas - That's already accounted for, since that's a T0 win, not a T1 win.  T0 on the draw is faster than T1 on the play.  (T0 on the play is impossible against an opponent who makes no decisions because you never get priority, though you will occasionally see it by way of concession in Legacy tournaments when somebody Leyline of the Void's a Dredge deck, or if a combo deck mulligans to 0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Edit: Here's a more interesting infinite combo, still with 11 cards:***

Play [Darksteel Citadel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397853), tap for (1)
Play [Ornithopter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383334) for 0
Play [Mox Opal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=208248), tap for U
Play [Mox Opal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=208248) sacrificing the other one, tap for U
Play [Skill Borrower](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=179428) for 1UU, reveal [Krark-Clan Ironworks](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=51633)
Sacrifice Darksteel Citadel, Ornithopter, and Mox Opal to Skill Borrower for (6)
Play [Mimic Vat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=207883) for 3
Play [Ichor Wellspring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389551) for 2, but hold priority...
...Sacrifice the Ichor Wellspring to Skill Borrower for (2) and hold priority...
...Sacrifice Skill Borrower to itself for (2), imprinting onto Mimic Vat
...Tap Mimic Vat for 3, creating a token copy of Skill Borrower with haste
...Sacrifice Mimic Vat to the Skill Borrower token for (2)
...release priority, drawing Krark-Clan Ironworks and [Voltaic Construct](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=48141), revealing [Dreamstone Hedron](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405208)
Tap the Skill Borrower token for (3)
Play Voltaic Construct for 4
Pay 2 to untap the Skill Borrower token with Voltaic Construct, then tap it again for (3)
Repeat until you have infinite mana
Tap and sacrifice the Skill Borrower token for 3, drawing Dreamstone Hedron, Goblin Cannon, and ???
Play [Goblin Cannon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74271) for 4
Shoot your opponent for infinite with Goblin Cannon

**Turn 1 First Main Phase on the Play** - [Infinite Damage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74271), 11 cards

Play [Darksteel Citadel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397853), tap for (1)
Play [Ornithopter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383334) for 0
Play [Mox Opal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=208248), tap for U
Play [Mox Opal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=208248) sacrificing the other one, tap for U
Play [Mox Opal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=208248) sacrificing the other one, tap for U
Play [Krark-Clan Ironworks](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=51633) for 1UUU
Sacrifice Darksteel Citadel, Ornithopter, and Mox Opal to Krark-Clan Ironworks for (6)
Play [Ichor Wellspring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389551) for 2, drawing a card
Sacrifice Ichor Wellspring to Krark-Clan Ironworks, drawing a card, gaining (2)
Play [Myr Retriever](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389609) for 2
Sacrifice Myr Retriever to Krark-Clan Ironworks, returning Ichor Wellspring, gaining (2)
Play Ichor Wellspring for 2, drawing a card
Sacrifice Ichor Wellspring to Krark-Clan Ironworks, drawing a card, gaining (2) (6 mana, 3 cards)
Play [Locket of Yesterdays](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=113513) for 1
Play [Goblin Cannon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74271) for 4
Play [Myr Retriever](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389609) for 1

Sacrifice Myr Retriever to Krark-Clan Ironworks returning Myr Retriever, play it, repeat until you have infinite mana, then blow Goblin Cannon for infinite damage

*Older Solutions:*

**Turn 2 Combat on the Play** - 11 infect.

*Turn 1:*
Play [Inkmoth Nexus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=213731), tap for (1)
Play [Ornithopter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383334) for 0
Play [Springleaf Drum](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=378534) for 1, tap it and Ornithopter for U
Play [Mox Opal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=208248), tap for U
Play [Arcbound Ravager](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370510) for UU (1 counter)
Sac Mox Opal to Ravager (2 counters)
Play [Mox Opal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=208248), tap for U
Play [Adventuring Gear](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=178135) for U

*Turn 2:*
Tap Springleaf Drum and Ornithopter for U
Activate Inkmoth Nexus for U
Tap Mox Opal for U
Equip Adventuring Gear to Nexus for U
Play [Polluted Delta](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405104), fetch for Island (+4/+4 to Nexus)
Sac Mox Opal, Springleaf Drum, Ornithopter, and Adventuring Gear to Ravager (6 counters)
Sac Ravager to itself, transfer all 6 counters to Inkmoth Nexus

Attack with [Inkmoth Nexus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=213731) for 11 Infect

Comment: Not sure how I forgot about Ravager

Comment: This doesn't work, you can't tap spring-leaf drum for (1) :P Just kidding ofcourse, i was about to post something quite similiar, good thing you saved me the trouble :)

Comment: Sure I can, colorless is now an official mana type. :p

Comment: I had a suspicion there was an eggs solution possible. And colorless is still not a color XD

Comment: You cannot tap Springleaf Drum for {C}. Colorless is not a color, and never has been. It has always been a *type* of mana, but Springleaf Drum specifically says "color". It doesn't actually matter, though, because you can use any type of mana to activate Inkmoth Nexus.

Comment: Oh, right you are.  I'll go make it U, because I feel any combo can use more U.

Comment: Alright, I think my solution is optimal.  I don't believe you can set up an infinite combo in fewer cards pre-combat turn 1 on the play, and there's no way to win on turn 0 at instant speed with artifacts.

Comment: I agree that this seems optimal (you found the same solution as I did in testing), but I'll leave the puzzle open for a day or two in case anyone finds a better one.

Comment: Upgraded to Goblin Cannon for entertainment value.

Comment: What are you sacrificing the Mox Opals to at the beginning?

Comment: State-based actions and the Legend Rule.

Comment: Ah, they're legendary. That does complicate things.

Comment: Among other things, it prevents degenerate decks from playing three of them and using them to give each other metalcraft so they can pretend they're playing a vintage deck in modern.

Comment: minor nitpick: The legend rule doesn't cause you to sacrifice it but puts it in your graveyard. The result is the same but it wouldn't trigger an opponent's [It That Betrays](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=401685). And nice job with that result!

Comment: Any day you get to kill somebody with a Goblin Cannon is a good day.  It's the unappreciated little brother to Goblin Charbelcher.

Comment: @Zerris, check my second solution with only 7 cards. too bad not really infinite :)

Comment: I noticed!  Unfortunate that you can't take actions during the resolution of that ability to keep re-ordering your deck.  I came up with another combo myself, which is a lot cuter (though no more efficient).

Comment: I can also go infinite off Knowledge Pool or Kuldotha Forgemaster, but neither is 11 cards or less.

Comment: That Skill Borrower solution is incredibly cool. Speaking of Magic puzzles, I'm personally working on the challenge of "Design a (shuffled) deck with the highest-possible turn 1 win rate", using a computer to simulate playing the deck to find its win rate. It's a little too programming-intensive to be suitable for public Stack Exchange, but would you be interested in working with me privately?

Comment: I assume the answer is Vintage Storm dropping all the anti-counterspell measures, since that's basically the goal of that deck.  Possibly Vintage Charbelcher, since Charbelcher's main weakness is counterspells.  Either way, I doubt you'll stray too far from a commonly played deck, since those conditions are close to tournament play.

Comment: Oh, I should have clarified, it's for Modern (because Modern has no Force to interact with). Of course this means the win rate is lucky to top 1%, but it's a silly exercise.

Comment: You can probably do better than 1%...  I'd try variants of Grishoalbrand or Amulet Bloom with 8 Gitaxian Probe / Street Wraith and 8 Chancellor of the Tangle / Simian Spirit guide.  You could also try modern storm, removing all the lands, but that seems hard.

Comment: I achieved about 0.5% with a Kiln Fiend deck, and 1% with Amulet Bloom (using Edge of Autumn too, surprisingly all four copies is optimal), but somehow Chancellor is a card I totally forgot about, which will probably help the decks immensely, thanks for that tip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34399/discussion-between-zerris-and-ninety-three).

Comment: Thinking about it, it technically isn't infinite damage because the Goblin Cannon abilities resolve one at a time so the game ends after dealing 20 damage :P

Comment: We've had this argument before, but it is (in my mind, at least) a stupid argument.  By the same argument, Splinter Twin isn't infinite, because you must enter combat at some point, and when you do so, you only have finite attackers.  But this is a silly distinction for optimization, since for any arbitrary value X, I *could* have dealt more than X damage.  Same goes for a card like Maga, Traitor to Mortals - you can't actually declare X = infinite.  So I'd like to propose that any strategy that could kill a person with an arbitrary life total using damage has done infinite damage.

Comment: I figured out a way to get this down to ten cards. Stack your deck Darksteel Citadel, Ornithopter, Mox, Mox, Skill Borrower, Ichor Wellspring, Voltaic Construct, KCI, Golem Artisan, Dreamstone Hedron. Play Skill Borrower and KCI mox+thopter+citadel to float six, holding priority play and KCI the Wellspring, draw KCI, activate Golem to haste Borrower, draw Golem, tap Borrower for 3, play Voltaic, untap Borrower, make infinite mana, play Golem Artisan, make Skill Borrower infinitely large and attack.

Comment: You're entirely right.  No idea how I missed that card when looking for haste artifacts.

Answer (score 5):

**First solution: Turn 1 infinite damage, 15 cards**

Play Darksteel Citadel, tap for 1
Cast Ornithopther
Cast Mox Opal, tap for U
Cast Mox Opal, tap for U
Cast Mox Opal, tap for U
Cast Krark-clan Ironworks.
Sacrifice Citadel to Ironworks
Cast Ichor Wellspring and sac it. *(2 cards in hand, 2 mana in pool)*

Cast Locket of Yesterdays
Cast Ichor Wellspring and sac it
Cast Ichor Wellspring and sac it
Cast Ichor Wellspring and sac it. *(4 cards in hand, 4 mana in pool)*

Cast Myr Retriever and sacrifice it.
Cast Myr Retriever and sacrifice it, returning other Myr Retriever. repeat infinite number of times, generates infinite mana.

Cast Lightning greaves
Cast Sigil of Distinction with all mana

Equip to Ornithopther and attack.

**Second solution: Turn 1 (deck size - 8)*2 damage, 7 cards**

Play Darksteel Citadel, tap for 1
Cast Ornithopther
Cast Mox Opal, tap for U
Cast Mox Opal, tap for U
Cast Mox Opal, tap for U
Cast Krark-clan Ironworks
Sacrifice Citadel, Ornithopter, Mox and Ironworks itself to Ironworks for 8 mana.
Cast Goblin Charbelcher and activate it!
Let the rest of your deck consist of only nonland cards, except for the last one. That one is a Mountain

***Not infinite because the rules require your deck to be of a size that you still can shuffle, too bad. Otherwise infinite***

Comment: I had just come up with an infinite turn 1 combo, but the Ichor Wellspring and Locket of Yesterdays in place of Chromatic Star + Dreamstone Hedron and Etherium Sculptor shaved off a lot of wasted cards, so I hope you don't mind me stealing that tech! :D

Comment: @IvoBeckers Changing my vote to this for creativity and efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

T2 Combat:

T1: Mox Opal, Inkmoth Nexus, Ornithopter, SpringLeaf Drum, Cranial Plating
T2: Darksteel Citadel, Animate Inkmoth, equip Cranial, Bone Saw, equip Bone Saw, Ornithopter - 10 Infect damage

T2 Draw Combat:

T1: Mox Opal, Inkmoth Nexus, Ornithopter, SpringLeaf Drum, Cranial Plating
T2: Darksteel Citadel, Animate Inkmoth, equip Cranial, Ornithopter, Ornithopter, Ornithopter - 10 Infect damage

Comment: @dpwilson Ornithopter + Springleaf = 1 mana

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that immediately after I commented, hence the deletion :P

Comment: @Dpwilson Makes sense, tis too bad I couldn't see the deletion : p

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Turn 2 Play Combat - 11 Infect Damage**

- Turn 1 on play:
  Inkmoth Nexus -> Paradise Mantle -> Mishra's Bauble -> Mox Opal -> Arcbound Ravager -> Sac Mox Opal to Arcbound for 1 counter -> Mox Opal - > Equip Paradise Mantle to Arcbound Ravager -> Sacrifice Mishra’s Bauble
- Turn 2 
  Darksteel Citadel -> Activate Inkmoth - > Tap Arcbound, Mox Opal for Mana -> Chromatic Star Chromatic Star -> Sacrifice both chromatic stars and Mox Opal -> 3 counters 2 cards -> Mox Opal -> Chromatic Star -> Sacrifice Paradise Mantle, Mox Opal, Chromatic Star, Darksteel Citadel -> 4 counters, 1 card -> Darksteel Relic -> Sacrifice Darksteel relic -> 1 counter -> Sacrifice Arcbound Ravager -> 10 counters on Inkmoth -> Swing for 11 Infect Damage

**Turn 2 Draw Combat**

- Turn 1 on draw:
  Inkmoth Nexus -> Springleaf Drum -> Memnite -> Mox Opal -> Cranial Plating -> Mox Opal -> Mox Opal -> Cranial Plating
- Turn 2 
  Darksteel Citadel -> Activate Inkmoth -> Equip both Cranial Platings

In play: 2 Cranial Plating, Inkmoth Nexus, Mox Opal, Darksteel Citadel, Springleaf Drum, Memnite
In graveyard: 2 Mox Opal

7 artifacts in play with Inkmoth active, Inkmoth Nexus swings for 15 Infect damage.

Answer (score 0):

**Before the second turn*, infinite damage.**

numbers between brackets indicate i tapped things and it made mana.

> darksteel citadel (1), memnite, mox opal x4 (5) [Timesifter](http://magiccards.info/mi/en/262.html),
> opponent takes his turn, reveals island, you reveal something cmc 1 (over and over ofcourse) so you have 30 turns to win in any way you like before the start of your normal second turn. For instance by doing the combo Zerris suggested, Etherium sculptor + 2 myr retrievers + blasting station + krak-clan Ironworks, but spread out over turns 1.1 to 1.10   
> **depending on how extra turns are viewed*

Comment: I feel this should count as winning on turn 2, because your opponent gets one turn, then you go infinite. In general, winning with infinite turns should count as winning on the turn you started taking infinite turns, I'll update the scoring to reflect that.

Comment: @Ninety-Three you start taking extra turns after the opponents upkeep BEFORE your regular turn though, but ofcourse it's a bit about how you call it and I mostly posted it because it abuses the fact your opponent only has islands :)

Comment: Your extra turn occurs after their entire turn, not just after their upkeep. You haven't started your normal second turn, but "You took a turn, then your opponent took a turn, then you took a turn and went infinite" feels like a turn 2 victory to me.

Comment: @Ninety-Three You're the boss, but i never took my regular second turn, is all i'm saying, so our feelings on the subject differ a bit :) (Then again, it could also be ruled as a turn 12 win, so turn 2 isn't that bad :P). Anyway, Ivo beckers has a faster win so it hardly matters :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't worry too much about extra turns when writing up the challenge because I knew there was turn one victory. I'll keep this sort of thing in mind if extra turns are potentially relevant to a future puzzle, I'm sure there's some unambiguous way to write the scoring criteria. Maybe something about how many main phases the opponent gets, that leaves room for alt-wins like mill too...

Comment: @ninety-three I could do this on the play before my second turn as well, which would make it equal to a turn 1 on the draw? ;)

Comment: @Drunkwolf Issue is, I would personally rule this as T1 opponent's upkeep, since that's when you gain your first extra turn, which is later than both of the top solutions.

Comment: @Waterseas I know the solution isn't a contender for first place. We're basically discussing where we should place it if it were